# Generalized matrix determinant lemma for pseudo-determinant of symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, determinants

The [pseudo-determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-determinant) of a square matrix $A$ is the product of its nonzero eigenvalues. Consider the [generalized matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma#Generalization) $$\det(A+UWV^\top) = \det A\det W\det(W^{-1} + V^\top A^{-1}U),$$ valid for invertible $A$ and $W$. I want to extend it to the pseudodeterminant. I proved that, if $\operatorname{im} U \subseteq \operatorname{im} A$, $A$ is symmetric, $U=V$, and $W$ is invertible, then $$\operatorname{pdet}(A + UWU^\top) = \operatorname{pdet} A\det W \det(W^{-1} + U^\top W^{-1} U^\top).$$ The proof is as follows: $$\begin{align}
\det(A + (I - AA^+) + UWU^\top) &= \det(A + (I - AA^+) + AA^+ UWU^\top AA^+) \\
&= \operatorname{pdet}(A + UWU^\top) = \\
&= \det(A + (I - AA^+))\det W \det(W^{-1} + U^\top (A + (I - AA^+))^{-1} U) = \\
&= \operatorname{pdet} A \det W \det(W^{-1} + U^\top A^+ U).
\end{align}$$ I'd mainly like to relax the assumption $\operatorname{im} U \subseteq \operatorname{im} A$, but I have not found a way. Is there a known theorem?